# How to check if a nullable type has a value from MemberInfo

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have the `MemberInfo` of a nullable type how can I determine if it has been assigned a value?

Comment: please elaborate more... what have you tried ? what didn't work ? any error messages / exceptions ? please show some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MemberInfo` doesn't have a means of obtaining a value, as `MemberInfo` could refer to a method, a property, or a field. Each of these has their own type that inherits from `MemberInfo`, which are (respectively) `MethodInfo`, `PropertyInfo`, and `FieldInfo`. Each of these types has its own means of obtaining a value from a target instance (I'll use a variable called `instance` to refer to the instance in question):

- `MethodInfo` - To invoke a function and obtain the return value, call [`object value = methodInfo.Invoke(instance, parameters)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx). See the linked page for information on what `parameters` should be.
- `PropertyInfo` - To obtain the value of a property, call [`object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, indexer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx). See the linked page for information on what `indexer` should be.
- `FieldInfo` - To obtain the value of a field, call [`object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(instance)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx).

**TL;DR Version of below**: To check if the value is null, just do this:

```
if (value == null)
{
    ...
}
```

Once you have the value from calling the appropriate method above, you can use that value for comparison purposes. When `Nullable<T>` is boxed, special rules apply; when a "null" value of `Nullable<T>` is boxed, then an actual null reference is returned. When a non-null `Nullable<T>` is boxed, the underlying value is what's boxed (in other words, instances of `Nullable<T>` are never actually boxed onto the heap). This example may make it a little clearer:

```
int? foo = 10;
int? bar = null;
int baz = 10;

object value;

value = foo; // The integer 10 is boxed and placed on the heap
value = bar; // Nothing is boxed and value is set to null
value = baz; // The integer 10 is boxed and placed on the heap
```

Because of these special rules, you can compare it against `null` to see if it's a null value, you can cast directly to the primitive type (which will cause a runtime exception if it's null or not of that type), or you can do a conditional cast back to the nullable type, which will give you back your nullable value.:

```
if (value == null)
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
int val = (int)value;
```

or

```
int? val = value as int?;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `MemberInfo` is a `PropertyInfo`

```
PropertyInfo prop = ...
object value = prop.GetValue(instance, null);
if (value != null)
{
    ...
}
```